# tools for symbolic execution on binaries

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir, klee, symbolic-execution

are there any tools for symbolic execution on binaries. i mean using which, we do not require to modify the source code - like klee_make_symbolic
or we can do such changes in IR (llvm ir etc.)
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe [miasm](https://github.com/cea-sec/miasm) can fit your requirements. It is a reverse engineer framework that supports static symbolic execution. As far as I know， it is more simple than KLEE and S2E.

Comment: Thanks! It is much closer to what I was looking for !

Answer (score 1):

Canonical list is in [Awesome Symbolic Execution](https://github.com/ksluckow/awesome-symbolic-execution#binaries).

Answer (score -2):

Symbolically executing binary code is **much much** harder, so i doubt there are such tools exist.

However note that you don't necessarily need to modify your code when using KLEE because it can model POSIX environment and C library (when compiled with support for this, of course). Using these features you can automatically symbolize `argv` arguments and keyboard interaction.

Comment: thanks for your answer. it helps!i am aware of mcsema and s2e but i am looking for something simpler

Comment: You can also search for `cloud9`, a symbolic interpreter based on KLEE.

Comment: There are many tools for symexec of binaries, both proprietary and open-source.